# SpriteKit view throwing NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have this code below that loads a scene in the `viewDidLoad:` method.

```
SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;
spriteView.showsDrawCount = YES;
spriteView.showsNodeCount = YES;
spriteView.showsFPS = YES;
PFPiePlanesScene *scene = [PFPiePlanesScene sceneWithSize:self.view.frame.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
[spriteView presentScene:scene];
```

When I call anything on the `spriteView`, it crashes with this message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setShowsDrawCount:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9685030'
```

I assume this is because it is not treating the instance as a SKView and instead as a UIView.

Thanks in advance.

Some extra:

Sprite kit uses this code to load a *scene*.

```
// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
skView.showsFPS = NO;
skView.showsNodeCount = NO;

// Create and configure the scene.
self.scene = [SKMyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
self.scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

// Present the scene.
[skView presentScene:self.scene];
```

### And, with no error. The classes are the exact same. Would just coming into the view screw this up?

Joe

Comment: It's simply not that class. Try printing in debug mode - it will not cast UIView to SKView - if it's not SKView :)

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski This has worked before. What do you meane by "debug mode?" How do I access this?

Comment: "Sprite kit uses this code to load a view." Where did you get that from? Also what is `self.view`?

Comment: Well, since this is in a view controller, `self.view` is the view controlled by the view controller. By view I mean scene. Will edit. @Sebastian

Comment: But what is the class of `self.view`?

Comment: @user2441712 Can you post a link to the sample code?

Comment: `- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;
    spriteView.showsDrawCount = YES;
    spriteView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    spriteView.showsFPS = YES;
}` from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

Comment: Have you done step 1: "Open the storyboard for the project. It has a single view controller (SpriteViewController). Select the view controller’s view object and change its class to SKView."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.view` is a `UIView` object. Simply casting the pointer does not make it a different type of object.

```
SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;
```

`spriteView` is now pointing to the object, that `self.view` is pointing to, telling the compiler, that it actually points to an object of type `SKView`. That's why you don't get any compiler errors or warnings. At runtime you are sending messages that can't be handled by `spriteView` because it is still just a `UIView` object.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do exactly. You could add an `SKView` object as a subview to your view, or make sure that your view controller has an `SKView` as it's root view.

Comment: Simply click on the view controller in the story board, then click on 'View' in the tree, then and set the custom class to SKView on the right hand side.

Answer (score 7):

If you are following apple's walk-thougrh you skipped the part : "Open the storyboard for the project. It has a single view controller (SpriteViewController). Select the view controller’s view object and change its class to SKView.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget add SpriteKit.framework under Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

Cheers,
Jesse

Answer (score 1):

what you have to do is to change the subclass of view from UIView To SKView select ur viewcontroller under that view and change it subclass

Answer (score 0):

@Sebastian is not correct.

i guess you are following apple's walk-thougrh.
maybe the following tutorial will help:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/49625/sprite-kit-tutorial-space-shooter

Answer (score 0):

Before casting your UIView to SKView , you must make sure to set your custom class as SKView in your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice the first view controller comes with these imports in the header file.

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

`#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>`

When you create a new view controller, by default Spritekit is not included. After adding sprite kit it should work with the default code apple provides

Comment: and change UIViewcontroller in the class's header which isn't working to SKView

Comment: Solved it by just adding an intermediary Skview class which is initialized instead of taking the UIViewcontroller's view!