# Weird error when initializing SKView

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

[image]

I have this block of code on my project to practice SpriteKit. But, for some unexpected reason, it gives me this error(compiles fine).
[image]

Just for the reference, I don't have anything on my HelloScene.h file. I hope this doesn't matter. There's nothing else other than these code. So, I can't see why this is happening. Can anyone tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: Show the logs. The reason should be given.

Comment: Do you mean the yellow warning sign?

Comment: No: `View/Debug Area/Show debug Area`. When it crashes, message should appear their.

Comment: Oh, it says `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setShowsDrawCount:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109f2a510'
` ... any clue?

Comment: `Unrecognized selector sent to instance` is a well known issue. I'd suggest your read about it in case you'll see it again in the future. Anyway, you could check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277246/spritekit-view-throwing-nsinvalidargumentexception

Comment: also not that before presenting the scene in viewDid/WillLayoutSubviews you have to check whether spriteView.scene is nil - only then present the scene otherwise rotating the device or other events can cause the initial scene to be re-presented.

Answer (score 1):

Check your storyboard, the view inside your ViewController should be SKView instead of UIView.